# Dúvida com ViewData usando o asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Fiz um exemplo para teste usando o ViewData, aparentemente deveria funcionar, mais está me gerando um erro de referência, conforme mensagem abaixo.

> The type or namespace name 'Aluno' could not be found

Fiz uma referência para **IList** e **IEnumerable** e não funciona, agradeço se alguém poder me indicar alguma solução.

No meu controller tenho:

```
//classe aluno
public class Aluno
{
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public double Idade { get; set; }
}

//action resulte para teste
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
    IList<Aluno> alunos = new List<Aluno>();
    alunos.Add(new Aluno { Nome = "Marcos", Idade = 5 });
    alunos.Add(new Aluno { Nome = "Paulo", Idade = 10 });
    alunos.Add(new Aluno { Nome = "Maria", Idade = 15 });
    ViewData["RecebeAluno"] = alunos;
    return View();
}
```

Na view tenho:

```
@foreach (var p in ViewData["RecebeAluno"] as List<Aluno>)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@p.Nome</li>
        <li>@p.Idade</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Dentro da sua View é necessário fazer o `using` do `namespace` do Aluno ou colocar a referencia com caminho completo. Poderia adicionar na pergunta o `namespace`  completo da classe Aluno, assim posso exemplificar?

Comment: @Barbetta, perfeito a sua resposta, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a mensagem diz "The type or namespace name 'Aluno' could not be found", não foi possível encontrar o tipo ou o namespace Aluno. Para utilizar um objeto dentro da view é necessário ou colocar o caminho completo ou o `using`.

```
@using SuaAplicaCao.Models


@foreach (var p in ViewData["RecebeAluno"] as List<Aluno>)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@p.Nome</li>
        <li>@p.Idade</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Ou

```
@foreach (var p in ViewData["RecebeAluno"] as List<SuaAplicaCao.Models.Aluno>)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@p.Nome</li>
        <li>@p.Idade</li>
    </ul>
}
```